# use substring to seperate 3 strings in SQL statement

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

I have am trying to use substring to seperate 3 strings in my sql statement, and display them into 3 different labels. 
At the moment I have this

```
string sql = "SELECT TOP 1 IncType + '-' + IncCost + '-' + IncDate FROM Incomings WHERE CONVERT(DATETIME, IncDate, 103) > GETDATE() ORDER BY IncDate";
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("MYCONNECTION"))
        {

            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn);
            conn.Open();
            string getValue = Convert.ToString(cmd.ExecuteScalar());

            lblNextInc.Text = (getValue);

            conn.Close();


        }
```

I am just trying to display it to one string for now but I'm getting the error message "Error converting data type varchar to float."

I'm not sure why I am getting this. The end result will be to get the two values and display them to two different labels (eg display incCost to lblOne, incType to lblTwo, incDate to lblThree)
Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: try SELECT TOP 1 CONCAT(inctype,'-',inccost,'-',incdate) FROM ....

Comment: Thanks for your input

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
string sql = "SELECT TOP 1 cast(IncType as nvarchar)+ '-'+ cast(IncCost as nvarchar) + '-' + cast(IncDate as nvarchar) FROM Incomings WHERE CONVERT(DATETIME, IncDate, 103) > GETDATE() ORDER BY IncDate";
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("MYCONNECTION"))
        {

            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn);
            conn.Open();
            string getValue = Convert.ToString(cmd.ExecuteScalar());

            lblNextInc.Text = (getValue);

            conn.Close();


        }
```

Comment: @Stuart please accept as answer if it solves your problem ;)